# Decide whether a polynomial has a root

Tags: undecidability, polynomials, computable-analysis

Let $A$ be a ring such that all elements of $A$ are complex computable numbers. I'm interested in knowing whether the decision problem that asks, given $P\in A[X]$, if $P$ has a root in $A$ is decidable.

I know that this problem is decidable for the following rings:

- $\mathbb{Z}$, since we can easily bound the absolute value of any root of $P\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ ;
- the field of fractions of a ring $A$ for which the problem is decidable, by Gauss lemma ;
- any algebraically closed field, in particular the field of computable complex numbers ;
- the field of computable real numbers, as a corollary of Sturm's theorem, as pointed out in [this comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131230/decide-whether-a-polynomial-has-a-root#comment276353_131230) ;

Is there some general result on the decidability  of this class of problems, maybe by making extra assumptions on $A$? Do we know if there are rings for which this decision problem is undecidable?

Comment: $A'=\mathbb{R}$ is easily decided using [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) and so do all the cases in the last paragraph.